# pyes 'from' keyword can't be set

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

Since `from` is a special python keyword I am not able to pass it `pyes.es.search` function. It give syntax error. `pyes.es.search(maf, "twitter", "tweet", sort="timestamp", size=2, from=3)` . I passed keyword arguments containing `from` also as below but `from` did not work while other worked.

```
keywords = {'sort': 'timestamp', 'size':3, 'from':2}
r = pyes.es.search(maf, "twitter", "reply",**keywords)
```

This problem also available for another python elasticsearch module here [here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch). In search function interface there is `from` argument.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I am stuck to the same pbm

Comment: I am using second module and passing `from`keyword in `body` . [here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch). I prefer second module not only for this problem, also readability of the queries are better since typing it explicitly in body variable with same syntax of original elastic search api.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with start parameter?

It sounds like the one to use.

See http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/pyes.queryset.html#pyes.queryset.QuerySet.start

Comment: No, I didn't. If I try it I will say the result here.